# Order by first row,last row and rest with 2 tables in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I have following two tables. I need to merge 2 tables based also sorted on
few conditions.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t1

CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    value INT
)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t2

CREATE TABLE #t2
(
    id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    value int
)

INSERT INTO #t1 (value) 
VALUES (1), (30), (19), (10), (40);

INSERT INTO #t2 (value)  
VALUES (100), (70), (20);

SELECT * FROM #t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM #t2
```

I need to union 2 tables and sorted value based on below condition

1. `#t1` first row (fixed)
2. `#t1` last row  (fixed)
3. `#t1` rest (other than first row) based on value
   4  `#t2` only sorted based on value

Expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: In your first table, the "first" row is not 1 and the "last" is not 40, not unless you also include another column which maintains that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using `varchar` to store numeric value ? you will need to perform a `cast() or convert()` before you will be to sort it.

Assumption : by `first` or `last` you are referring with row with `minimum` and `maximum` value in column `id`.

```
select  value, seq as [order]
from
(
    select  id, value, 
            seq = case when row_number() over(order by id) = 1 then 1 
                       when row_number() over(order by id desc) = 1 then 2
                       else 3
                       end
    from    #t1

    union all

    select  id, value, seq = 4
    from    #t2
) d
order by seq, convert(int, value)
```

Comment: then you can remove the `CONVERT()` in the `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

You can check this below logic of ordering the output using CASE statement in the ORDER clause-

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    select 'T1' T_Name,* from #t1
    union
    select 'T2',* from #t2
)A
ORDER BY 
CASE 
    WHEN t_name = 'T1' AND id = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #t1) THEN 1
    WHEN t_name = 'T2' AND id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #t2) THEN 2
    WHEN t_name = 'T1' THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END, 
Id -- Or you can order by Value. Just keep in mind that Value is VARCHAR as per your setup. So, Ordering will be also impact accordingly.
```